# How do I add sum and count on a pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

Here's my dataset

```
customer_id hour    size
1              0       1
1              1      18
2              1       7
```

Here's my code

```
table = a.pivot_table(index=['customer_id'], 
                      columns='hour', 
                      fill_value=0,
                      values='size')
```

Here's what I've got

```
hour            0   1
customer_id       
1               1  18
2               8   7
```

What I need

```
hour            0   1   count  sum
customer_id       
1               1  18       2   19
2               0   7       1    7
count           1   2
sum             1  25
```

`count` is `non-zero count` in a category and `sum` is sum in a category

Comment: Your output has `count` / `sum` rows *and* `count` / `sum` columns. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: @jpp You can answer if you have more complete answer by any existing library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible a bit dynamic solution is omit `fill_value=0`:

```
table = a.pivot_table(index='customer_id', 
                      columns='hour', 
                      values='size')
print (table)
hour           0     1
customer_id           
1            1.0  18.0
2            NaN   7.0

a = table.agg(['count','sum'])
b = table.T.agg(['count','sum']).T

print (table.fillna(0).append(a).join(b))
         0     1  count   sum
1      1.0  18.0    2.0  19.0
2      0.0   7.0    1.0   7.0
count  1.0   2.0    NaN   NaN
sum    1.0  25.0    NaN   NaN
```

Comment: why passing index in a list `index=['customer_id']`?

Comment: @pyd - not necessary

Comment: It is DataFrame

Comment: what is type(table) ?, I am getting `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'agg'` for `a = table.agg(['count','sum'])
`

Comment: @pyd - Use oldier pandas version, check [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html)

Comment: it is new in `pandas 0.20.0`